# Regex, match string 4 or 5 digits long between "\" and "\"

Tags: c#, regex

I need to build a regex. the string i want to match always starts with \ then 4 or 5 numbers then another \

For example.

1. Welcome Home<\217.163.24.49\7778\False,
2. Euro Server\217.163.26.20\7778\False,
3. Instagib!)\85.236.100.115\8278\False,

in first example i need "7778". In second example i need "7778". In third example i need "8278".

these 4 digit numbers is actually a port number, and its the only time on each line that this series of characters (eg, \7778\ ) would appear. sometimes the port number is 4 digits long, sometimes its 5.

I already know how to keep the string for later use using Regex.Match.Success, its just the actual regex pattern I am looking for here.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var match=Regex.Match(@"\1234\",@"\\(?<num>\d{4,5})\\"); 


if(match.Success)
{
    var numString=match.Groups["num"].Value;
}
```

or (if you don't like using groups) you can use lookbehind and lookahead assertions to ensure your 4-5 digit match is surrounded by slashes:

```
var match=Regex.Match(@"\1234\",@"(?<=\\)\d{4,5}(?=\\)");
if(match.Success)
{
    var numString=match.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@"\\(\d{4,5})\\"
```

`\\` to match a backslash, `\d` to match digits, `{4,5}` for "4 to 5". The parentheses around `\d{4,5}` make it so that you can access the number part with `.Groups[1]`.

Comment: hi sepp2k, i tried this and its keeping the "\" either side of the 4/5 digit number. i need just the number

Comment: @brux: As I said in my edit, the number will be in the first capturing group if you put the parentheses around `\d{4,5}`.

Comment: var match1 = Regex.Match(temp, @"\\\(\d{4,5})\\");
if (match1.Success) ipaddr.Text = match1.Captures[0].ToString();    the string in the text box is \7778\ not 7778 :s

Comment: @brux: Right, you need to do `Groups[1]`, not `Captures[0]` to access the content of the first group.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(\\[\d]{4,5}\\)`

Comment: Why the square brackets around \d?  That just makes it a set with one member.

Comment: i need to imit the when i use regex.match.success to get the matched string is there a way to omit the "\"'s?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a simple tool to verify regexes against example strings; this is a valid string for your samples in C#, it however is not 'strict'!

`(?<name>.+?)\\(?<ip>[0-9.]+)\\(?<port>[0-9]{4,5})\\(?<boolean>[False|True]+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
\\[0-9]{4,5}\\
```

\ It should start with \ (another \ is to escape)
[0-9] It could be any of the number mentioned in set (0,1,2,3...9)
{4,5} previous set can appear 4 to 5 times
\ It should end with \ (another \ is to escape)